# Ansible Windows win_unzip Method System.IO.Compression.ZipFile Exception calling ExtractToFile with 3 argument Access to the path is denied

Tags: windows, ansible, unzip, winrm

Using :

```
  win_unzip:
        src: "D:\program64\my\app\binaries.zip"
        dest: "D:\program64\my\app\"
        delete_archive: yes
```

i get :

```
TASK [ Unzip zip file] ****************************
17:19:01            fatal: [myhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "dest": "D:\program64\my\app\", "msg": 
"Error unzipping 'D:\program64\my\app\binaries.zip' to 'D:\program64\my\app\'!. Method: 
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Exception: Exception calling \"ExtractToFile\" with \"3\" argument(s): 
\"Access to the path 'D:\program64\my\app\my_app.exe' is denied.\"", "removed": false, "src": 
"D:\program64\my\app\binaries.zip"}
```

I check and there was no `my_app.exe` , when i did the extract manually it worked, i check also the policy they were ok, i think it is linked more to Windows than Ansible but can't figure out why and how.

PS : Using Kerberos auth manual.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In my case src: was accidentally a folder instead of a file.